# Flask WTF Forms and CSRF Token when using Bootstrap Modal Form (without JS)

Tags: flask, bootstrap-modal, csrf, flask-wtforms

After learning from the Flask Mega-Tutorial by Miguel Grinberg I have created a dashboard, where the user has a list of searches he has added/saved to his account. I added a delete button to every search that is listed on the dashboard. This button is switching a modal where the user is presented with the option to apply the delete or cancel.

I have read several articles on the topic but could not find an answer to my question if the form is actually protected by a CSRF token.

- WTF Form for the modal:

```
class DeleteSearchForm(FlaskForm):
    submit                      = SubmitField('Delete')
    cancel                      = SubmitField(label='Cancel', render_kw={'formnovalidate': True})
```

Actually not using the cancel button, as that one only needs to dismiss the modal.

- Sub-template for the modal trigger button and the modal form, gets pre-rendered for each search on the dashboard (no JavaScript needed):

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{s.search_id}}">
        Delete
      </button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{s.search_id}}">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle{{s.search_id}}">Delete Search permanently</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

              <h4>Search Name: {{s.search_name}}</h4>
              <h4 style="text-align: right;">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <form action="{{ url_for('main.search_del2', search_id=s.search_id) }}" method="post">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am actually only using `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` from the wtf-form here, the buttons are "hardcoded", but I could also use `{{ form.submit() }}` to render the delete button which would work as well.

- Dashboard route:

```
@bp.route("/dashboard")
@login_required ## view only accessible if logged in
def dashboard():
    user_searches = current_user.get_user_searches()

    ## form stuff for delete modal forms
    form = DeleteSearchForm()
    current_app.jinja_env.globals['abs'] = abs
    return render_template('dashboard_04.html'
                         , title='Dashboard'
                         , searches=user_searches
                         , form=form
                         )
```

- route/view function that will execute the delete if the user applies it in the modal (technically not a view function since it does not render any html):

```
@bp.route('/search_del2/<search_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def search_del2(search_id):
    search = Search.query.filter_by(search_id=search_id).one()
    form = DeleteSearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        db.session.delete(search)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Search has been deleted', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard'))
    flash('No changes made.', 'info')
    return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard'))
```

So basically the form is **instantiated when the dashboard view function** is called and for every search in the list a hidden modal form including the hidden CSRF token (`{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`) is rendered. When the user clicks the modal-toggle Delete button, the hidden modal form for the respective search_id is shown.

If the user then applies the deletion by clicking the Delete (submit) button on the modal form, **the view function search_del2 is called** to execute the delete on the database  (`<form action="{{ url_for('main.search_del2', search_id=s.search_id) }}" method="post">`).

So my question is: Since the form is not validated by the route that instantiated it (dashboard) but another route (search_del2), is the hidden CSRF token actually being evaluated?

NB: I am also using flask-bootstrap (bootstrap 3)

Are there any other things I should be aware of, when handling forms like this with a modal?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: CSRF is validated when you call `validate_on_submit()` on a form instance. It does not matter how the form was rendered of where. All you need to do to confirm this is remove the hidden tag and see how your form submissions fail.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you, I tired it without the hidden token and it failed like you said. Good to know it works like this!